# Remove post from new menu in top bar

Tags: admin

I have removed the post menu from the admin side bar like so:

```
add_action('admin_menu','remove_default_post_type');

function remove_default_post_type() {
    remove_menu_page('edit.php');
}
```

How can I now remove it from the top bar 'new' menu as well?

Answer (score 5):

The users can still create new posts if the URL is known, like;
`domain.com/wp-admin/post-new.php`

Here is the code you can use for that ... added it to the file `functions.php`

```
function hide_add_new() {
global $submenu;
    // For Removing New Posts from Admin Menu
    unset($submenu['post-new.php?post_type=post'][10]);
    // For Removing New Pages
    unset($submenu['post-new.php?post_type=page'][10]);
   // For Removing CPTs
    unset($submenu['post-new.php?post_type=custom_post_type'][10]);
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'hide_add_new');

//Thanks to Howdy_McGee
function remove_admin_bar_links() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-post');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-page');
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-cpt');
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_links' );


function disable_new_post() {
if ( get_current_screen()->post_type == 'my_post_type' )
    wp_die( "You ain't allowed to do that!" );
}
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'disable_new_post' );
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove submenus you can inspect the menu you will see every `li` will have an ID similar to `wp-admin-bar-new-content` to remove said menu item, just remove `wp-admin-bar-`. With that we can look at `+New -> Post` item which has an ID of `wp-admin-bar-new-post` so we can remove it like so:

```
function remove_admin_bar_links() {
        global $wp_admin_bar;
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-post');
    }
    add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_links' );
```

[Reference Link / Tutorial](http://sumtips.com/2011/03/customize-wordpress-admin-bar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code :

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpse126922_remove_newpost', 999 );

function wpse126922_remove_newpost ( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'new-post' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Abhik
this code worked for me:

```
function remove_admin_bar_links() {
global $wp_admin_bar;
$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-content');
$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-post');
$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-page');
$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_links' );
function disable_new_post() {
if ( get_current_screen()->post_type == 'post' )
    wp_die( "You ain't allowed to do that!" );
}
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'disable_new_post' );function disable_new_post() {
if ( get_current_screen()->post_type == 'my_post_type' )
    wp_die( "You ain't allowed to do that!" );
}
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'disable_new_post' );
```